# Why not automatically +1 an accepted answer?

Tags: feature-request

I see alot of times accepted questions with 0 votes (there is also a badge for such an answers)

Why not +1 the answer if the questioner accepted the answer and not +1 it yet,
people are losing points!

Comment: Just because the answer is accepted - doesn't mean that I found it helpful.  I'm not going to vote on something just because someone else liked it.

Comment: @Lix but if you are the questioner and you accept the answer it sat that it's help you, why not +1 if you already accepted it

Comment: For that answer to that you'll have to ask the relevant OP.  It really depends... In any case - it is the OP's decision whether to accept and vote or not...

Comment: And what happens when you post and accept an answer to your own question?

Comment: @Lix What OP stands for?

Comment: Original Poster - It means the person who originally created the post.  It is usually used to refer to the question asker - but it could just as easily be used to refer to the original person who posted an answer.

Comment: there is a badge for 0 accepted answer

Comment: new users also often don't have the rep to upvote. they can only accept.

Comment: How are you losing points when you +15 for an accepted answer?

Answer (score 12):

> people are losing points!

No they are not. They are simply not gaining them.

There is lots of pressure on new comers to accept answers - this sometimes results in answers being accepted without actually being helpful (or very good).

The decision to upvote is something separate from accepting an answer and should remain separate.

Comment: If you accept answer it's mean that it helps you, if not then unaccept it

Comment: @DorCohen - Does it? If you are told that "no one will answer your questions if you don't improve your accept rate", but you don't have any good answers on your questions, what do you do?

Comment: +1 @Oded I think you make a very good point, but then I think SO should address the issue of people feeling forced to accept answers to improve their accept rate, but then thats another topic..

Comment: @Curt - That is indeed another topic and has been discussed here before.

Answer (score 0):

**Accepting an answer:** It best solved my problem, among the different answers.

**Upvoting a post:** It is a good (ingenious, interesting, thorough, well-written, ...) post (question or answer, it doesn't matter). Could even not solve the question asked at all.

Quite different things. Both give reputation, in any case.